# Control the width of menu component in Material-UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to implement a menu item with a login form in it. It works but the width is too small. Is there a way to change it? I couldn't find anything in the documentation about it.

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';

export default function SimpleMenu() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button aria-controls="simple-menu" aria-haspopup="true" onClick={handleClick}>
        Open Menu
      </Button>
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with `makeStyles` which helps you customize built in components from Material-UI. From the documentation (read further here: [makeStyles](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook)):

> Link a style sheet with a function component using the hook pattern. This hook can be used in a function component. The documentation often calls this returned hook useStyles.

The only solution what was working for me is the following:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

// ...

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    customWidth: {
        '& div': {
            // this is just an example, you can use vw, etc.
            width: '350px',
        }
    }
});

// ...

export default function SimpleMenu() {
   // ...
   const classes = useStyles();

   return (
      <Menu
         id="simple-menu"
         anchorEl={anchorEl}
         keepMounted
         open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
         onClose={handleClose}
         className={classes.customWidth}
       >
         <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
         <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
         <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
       </Menu>
```

Additionally just checked the documentation and I even did not find any related property for this purpose, so I would go with the suggested custom solution.

Comment: Your answer could result in some unforeseen side effects and isn't how Material UI recommends setting sizing. Abdellah GRIBs answer should be the correct response

Answer (score 26):

@norbitrial answer could have side effects. In my case i can't close the menu by clicking outside it !

Better use :

```
<Menu
  ...
  PaperProps={{  
    style: {  
      width: 350,  
    },  
 }}
```

Comment: Works great, cleaner, and likely the preferred way to achieve this over "accepted" answer.

Answer (score 5):

In MUIv5 there is a straightforward way to handle this by passing the PaperProps argument to menu (menu inherits the arguments from Popover which are documented [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/popover/)).

Thus, you could create an 800px wide menu as follows

```
<Menu PaperProps={{sx: {width: '800px'}}}>
   ...
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add classes property to  component. Define a css file with that class and change the width there.

Also material-ui brings another way to do it with inline styles with useStyles and makeStyles. check material-ui documentation for that.

Answer (score 2):

The current accepted answer targets every div inside the Menu, which was not ideal in my case. The following worked for me:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => {
  return createStyles({
    menuRoot: {
      minWidth: "25vw",
    },
  });
});

export default function CustomMenu(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Menu
      id="simple-menu"
      anchorEl={anchorEl}
      keepMounted
      open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
      onClose={handleClose}
      transformOrigin={{
        vertical: "bottom",
        horizontal: "left",
      }}
      classes={{
        paper: classes.menuRoot,
      }}
    >
      ...
    </Menu>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Control the width of menu component in Material-UI

```
import {  Button,  Menu, MenuItem } from "@material-ui/core";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import style from "./filterBar.module.scss";


const Filterbar = () => {

  const [openMenu, setOpenMenu] = useState(null);
  const handleMenu = () => {
    setOpenMenu(true);
  };

  const closeMenu = ()=>{
      setOpenMenu(false)
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleMenu}>Filter</Button>
      <Menu open={openMenu} onClose={closeMenu}>
        <MenuItem onClick={closeMenu} >

        <div style={{display:'flex', justifyContent:"space-between", width:"50vw"}}>
            <h6>Brand</h6>
            <h6>Color</h6>
            <h6>Price</h6>
        </div>

        </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Filterbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have smth like the following:

```
<Menu className={classes.menu} />
 <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
 <Divider component="li" / >
</Menu>
```

You can fix width in the following way:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme>(() => ({
  menu: {
    '&  li': {
      maxWidth: '320px',
    },
  },
}));
```